# Threads process exiting before executing full code

Tags: c#

I have the code below that's supposed to allocate thread workers for each file inside `string[] files` to execute the code inside `ProcessFile()` inside the try-catch block.

However, most of the time the code inside `ProcessFile()` is not reached to the main functions that throw the exceptions I want to check for. I notice the behavior when debugging because the execution statements kept jumping between `Main()` and `ProcessFile()` before executing all the code inside `ProcessFile()` I'm assuming it's because the working threads are exited before finishing the program. I'm not sure how to handle this.

```cs
        static int workingCounter = 0;
        static int workingLimit = 1000;
        static int processedCounter = 0;

        static void Main() {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"DirectoryPath");
            int checkCount = files.Length;

            foreach (string file in files) {
                //wait for free limit...
                while (workingCounter >= workingLimit) {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
               workingCounter += 1;
                ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessFile);
                Thread th = new Thread(pts);
                th.Start(file);
            }

            //wait for all threads to complete...
            while (processedCounter < checkCount) {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Work completed!");
        }

        static void ProcessFile(object file) {
            try {

                string path = file.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " recieved: " + file + " thread count is: " + workingCounter.ToString());
                //make some sleep for demo...
                CSVBOM testing = new CSVBOM(path, CSVBOM.BOMFileType.csv);

                testing.FindHeaderRow(path);
                testing.GetIndexMap(path);
                testing.HeaderColumnParser(path);
                testing.SeparateIntFromString();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle your exception...
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Caught: {0} \n File{1}", ex.Message, file);
            }
            finally {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref workingCounter);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref processedCounter);
            }
        }
```

Comment: which version of c# and .net are you running against? unless you are studying specifically Threads and syncronization, would you consider to move your code to Tasks, instead?

Comment: " I notice the behavior when debugging because the execution statements kept jumping between Main() and ProcessFile()": it is normal when debugging multi-threaded application. Don't forget your main program is a thread too!

Comment: I'm running .Net 2.0 and cannot change it. What I'm trying to achieve is test the code I developed against a 150 files to look out for any exceptions caught.

Comment: Even if not using Tasks, you should still look into the Semaphore class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.8). It would replace your workingCounter and thread sleeps with a logical abstraction that does the same thing.

Comment: Well a weird conflict I noticed is when printing out `file` or `path` inside `ProcessFile()`, it's not the same as the variable `file` inside the catch block.

Comment: The code `workingCounter += 1;` is not threadsafe - you should be using `Interlocked.Increment` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without commenting on better designs, you need to fix any race conditions as well as tell the compiler that a variable [might be modified by multiple threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile).

First fix the declarations:

```
static volatile int workingCounter = 0;
const int workingLimit = 1000;
static volatile int processedCounter = 0;
```

Next fix any race conditions.  `workingCounter += 1` is the same as `workingCounter = workingCounter + 1`.  That might illustrate why this is NOT thread safe.

```
//Not thread safe
workingCounter  += 1;
```

Should be:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref workingCounter);
```